# @page :first suddenly stopped working with dompdf

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf

Yesterday I've performed a `composer update`, and I've noticed the following bit of code just gets ignored suddenly:

```
@page :first {
    margin: 0px 60px !important; 
    display:none !important; 
    border:none;
}
```

What this did before the update:

- Hides header and footer (on the first page)
- Removes the margins top and bottom (on the first page)

Both of those things just stopped working after an update. The header and footer show on the first page.
It looks like the `@page :first` part gets ignored somehow. There is nothing overwriting it and I've not changed any other code.

This happens while creating a PDF through **DOMPDF**.

Am I missing something?